# fileAge property only works sometimes

Tags: java, ftp, mule, mule-studio

I have a Mule flow that contains the following inbound endpoint:

```
    <inbound-endpoint address="${source.address}" doc:name="readInputGeneric0" mimeType="text/xml">
        <properties>
            <spring:entry key="pollingFrequency" value="${source.polling_frequency}" />
            <spring:entry key="fileAge" value="${source.fileAge}" />
            <spring:entry key="workDirectory" value="${work.address}" />
        </properties>
    </inbound-endpoint>
```

In production, the source.address property points to an ftp server, and source.fileAge property's value is 20000. Normally everything works ok. However, it's the second time in about two months, that I notice that the files on the ftp folder are not being read. To fix it I have to remove the fileAge property (I also tried to set it to 0, but it didn't work). The problem, is that I need the fileAge to ensure that a file is not being read while it's still being written. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Given the open issues: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7909 and https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7104. Can you specify the size of the files you are reading and the log of the ftp server including lock creation?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Victor. This happens with files from 1Mb to 20Mb. Concerning the logs, the level is WARN so you won't see the locks. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to be reported here (Though I'm using a different version of Mule):

http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/issues/i#browse/MIRTH-1990

Finally, I solved it replacing fileAge by sizeCheckWaitTime.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if it has to do with daylight savings time.

Have you restarted the runtime since the change of time?

Comment: Thanks for your answer joe. Yes, the server is restarted every day.